# How to import excel data with header info that is datetime

Tags: r, excel, datetime

I have trend energy from electric submeters. column headers are in date-time (example: `1/13/2017 0:00`,  `1/13/2017 0:15`...), below these headers are submeter consumption readings in whole numbers.

When I execute `read_excel()` the headers come into `R` in character format like `"424509.0129493"`. The column data below are numeric. I then execute a `gather` command and when I do the header date time decimals are all truncated to whole numbers, which removes my time interval information. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
meter_reads <- read_excel("_Jan to Feb meter data for Yardi.xlsx")
BoonShort <-  gather(meter_reads, Date, Value, 3:ncol(meter_reads))
```

Comment: can you convert the headers after reading using `as.Date`?

Comment: why not save it as a csv? I haven't had date issues when saving excel spreadsheet as a csv. `read.csv("FileName.csv", sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by separating the date part from the hour part using separate from tydir.

*Assuming df = "meter_reads", and dateTime column = "dateTimePart"

```
nuevoDf<-separate(data = meter_reads, col = dateTimePart, into = c("date","time"),sep = "\\.")
```

Now, excel gives you a numeric value that signifies the number of days that have gone by after Dec 30, 1899. So, all we need to do to convert the date column to a real date is add :

```
nuevoDf$realDate<- nuevaFecha<-as.POSIXct("1899-12-30")+nuevoDf$date*3600*24
```

**Notice that basically we added the number of seconds since then by getting 3600 * 24 (number of seconds in 1 day)

All right, finally, to get the hours:
So, excel basically gives you the fraction of the day that has gone by since 12am. All we have to do is get that fraction and convert it in seconds, like such:

```
nuevoDf$seconds<-nuevoDf$time*3600*24
```

Then, just add the seconds to your real date:

```
nuevoDf$realDate + nuevoDf$seconds
```